# Wrong format e-mail address - InternetAddress

Tags: java

I have a trouble with creating e-mail address with sent via `org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper`:

```
final InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("foo@example.com", "Two words");
```

and the result in received message is `From` in this format:

```
"Two words <foo@example.com>" <foo@example.com>
```

but what I want is this:

```
"Two words" <foo@example.com>
```

Q: What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

with version 1.5.0-b1 of javax.mail, the following program

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class Email {

    public Email() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, AddressException {


        final InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("foo@example.com", "Two words");

        System.out.println(from);
        final InternetAddress from2 = new InternetAddress("\"Two words\" <foo@example.com>");

        System.out.println(from2);
    }

}
```

outputs

```
Two words <foo@example.com> 
Two words <foo@example.com>
```

...

Comment: Do not understand how this should help me. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You are asking what is wrong with your code, but are providing only one line of code... So I tested that line of code and it produces what you seem to be expecting. So maybe you should provide some more, and precise the version of lib you're using...